# which software can view any developed software code?

Tags: programming-languages, code-view

I would to know the software which can view code of Microsoft word software and any other software code. So that I can learn from that software code and how they used in there.
(sound's like illegal but really it is helpful for the programmer)

any Ideas

Comment: I'd rather not try to learn from Microsoft Word sources... But learning from the source usually is a good idea. Just grab the sources of an OSS project you like and start reading.

Comment: I don't see why this is voted to close. Yes, it's not perfectly worded, but still a valid question.

Comment: Just take care that it might be illegal, in some countries, to do this decompilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called a disassembler or decompiler.  It is rarely useful for what you want it for, because the intent of the programmer expressed in variable, method, and class names - is mostly lost.  This is somewhat less true for modern bytecode languages like Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a decompiler for viewing the code of dll and exe files based on the language its coded in.

example:
Delphi Dll Decompiler

search for an appropriate decompiler te get the code back.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a decompiler. Please note decompiling is illegal in many juridictions. Also once you decompile you usually get very hard to read assembly code learning from which is problematic unless you have plenty of experience and know exactly what you're looking for.